# Slow loading and app crash while adding stackviews programatically in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I'm adding a bunch of stackviews(horizontal) to the vertical stack view programmatically inside a VIEWDIDLOAD method.Im adding this in almost 10 screens but while navigating to the respective screens it is taking almost 30 seconds to load and at some point while navigating it is taking too much and crashing the app.

Here is my view hierarchy for adding the views.

Vertical stackviews-->horizontal stackviews (view1+view2+view3+------depends will up to 7views)

In the above hierarchy I'm adiiding multiple views to the horizontal stack view and finally adding to the vertical stack view where it can iterate through 100 or 1500....

Please help me out of this problem to increase the app loading time and app crash issue....

Comment: Have you run Instruments to see what's going on? Sounds like a collection view is more suited for you than stack views.

Comment: `UIStackView` has really bad performance, unfortunatelly. While it is a great tool for fast prototyping and same basic layouts, you should avoid it when creating complicated layouts.

Comment: I'm creating a editable data grid where it is difficult to achieve using the collection view or table view.where it contains images,checkboxes with borders exactly like a data grid can you make any suggestions.Here number of columns can be vary where user can pass based on his needs

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with both Leo and Losiowaty -- UIStackView is meant for elementary layouts -- collection view is a much better option if you want performance.

Edit:

> What you're trying to do is difficult no matter which technique you
> use. Since you already have it working with auto layout alone, you
> probably understand it much better than you did when you set out.
> (and better than you will a week from now if you stop here)
>
> It will be worth your time to
> implement this with a collection view, since you'll have this issue
> again as you evolve your app. You'll find it can do what you need.
> Just tackle it in steps. There just isn't any "easy" solution if
> your data isn't easy.  Get started and ask questions when you get
> stuck. Include the code that illustrates how you're stuck. People here
> will be glad to help if you show your efforts. I know I will.

Comment: Hi,I'm creating a editable data grid where it is difficult to achieve using the collection view or table view.where it contains images,checkboxes with borders exactly like a data grid can you make any suggestions.Here number of columns can be vary where user can pass based on his needs